# animate src image change with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm building a simple html/css/vanilla js component to display images. I have the list of images on the top, and when I click on one of them, it must appear in the main container.
To do that I just change the `img` element src like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

    var mainImg =               document.getElementById("mainImg");
    var thumbnailContainer =    document.getElementById("thumbnailContainer");

    thumbnailContainer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

        var linkClicked =       event.target.currentSrc;
        mainImg.src =           linkClicked;

    });
});
```

Now I would like to add some animation, but I have some trouble with css `transition`, here's my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="mainImg" src="xxxxx" alt="car 2"/>
   <div id="thumbnailContainer" class="thumbnailContainer">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="xxxxx" alt="car 2"/>
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="xxxxxx" alt="car 2"/>
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="xxxxxx" alt="car 2"/>
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="xxxxxx" alt="car 2"/>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The thing that is bugging me is that the element that I click to trigger the transition doesn't need to change, but I just change the `src` property on the main image with JS.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Will the source of the full-size image be stored in a variable or do you want it to be something you can grab from the thumbnail element itself onClick?

Comment: I just assign the src of the thumbnail clicked with the src of the main image!

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, when you click on the thumbnail, it changes itself. The expected/desired behaviour is that the main image should change to a larger version of the thumbnail when clicked. I would suggest trying event.target.src as currentSrc returns a different value than src for the same URL.

Comment: Did you see the code? The image changing works, when the thumbnail is clicked, the main image changes, I just want to add animations!

Comment: I read the code. The way you've worded your problem isn't very clear. If your problem deals with CSS, you need to post the css you've also used or state you haven't got any styling. I feel as though your 'Did you see the code?' was rife with condescension, so rather than help you, I will take my leave. Good luck.